# What's the best way to stream mp4 video from Azure Media Services for IE8?

Tags: azure, azure-media-services

I am trying to host an mp4 video on Azure Media Services and play it on IE 8, so the html5 video tag is not an option. I have to use a flash player which is fine. Should I...

a) Upload the mp4 file to the blob storage and put the path to it into the video player, like so:

```
<object width="800" height="560" id="SamplePlayer">
    <param value="/Content/MediaServices/Player/StrobeMediaPlayback.2.0.swf" name="movie">
    <param value="src=@Url.Encode("https://mymediaservicestorage.blob.core.windows.net/asset-abcd/myvideoHD.mp4?sv=2012-02-12&sr=c&si=abcd&sig=abcd&st=2014-10-10T18%3A10%3A02Z&se=2016-10-09T18%3A10%3A02Z")" name="flashvars">
    <param value="true" name="allowFullScreen">
    <param value="always" name="allowscriptaccess">
    <param value="direct" name="wmode">
    <embed width="800" height="560" flashvars="src=@Url.Encode("https://mymediaservicestorage.blob.core.windows.net/asset-abcd/myvideoHD.mp4?sv=2012-02-12&sr=c&si=abcd&sig=abcd&st=2014-10-10T18%3A10%3A02Z&se=2016-10-09T18%3A10%3A02Z")" wmode="direct" allowfullscreen="true" allowscriptaccess="always" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" src="/Content/MediaServices/Player/StrobeMediaPlayback.2.0.swf">
</object>
```

Issues with a) The playback comes directly from blob storage, mymediaservicestorage.blob.core.windows.net. I do not think my reserved streaming units apply to blob storage.

OR

b) Encode the video using the "Playback on PC/Mac" option, and then my video player would be the same as in a) but the path would change to:

```
http://mymedia.streaming.mediaservices.windows.net/someguid/myvideoHD.ism/Manifest&AdaptiveStreamingPlugin_encryptionKeyToken=&autoPlay=true&plugin_AdaptiveStreamingPlugin=/Content/MediaServices/Player/MSAdaptiveStreamingPlugin-v1.0.10-osmf2.0.swf&AdaptiveStreamingPlugin_retryLive=true&AdaptiveStreamingPlugin_retryInterval=10
```

Issues with b) The file size went from a 15MB mp4 file to a 334MB ism/manifest file! So yeah maybe I am using my reserved streaming units but does that really do any good since the file is so large now?

Any help is truly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do serve your MP4 file directly from media services - there's no need to encode anything from it. So your workflow would be something like this:

- Create an asset in media services
- Create an asset file within the asset, and upload the mp4 file into it
- Create an origin locator for the asset
- Serve the mp4 file directly from: [http://*youraccount*.origin.mediaservices.net/*originlocatorid*/*your-file*.mp4](http://_youraccount_.origin.mediaservices.net/_originlocatorid_/_your-file_.mp4)

Comment: But MP4 is not a streaming media format, and so if I serve it directly from media services it won't utilize my reserved streaming units. Is that correct?

Comment: Technically it would still be a progressive download, but as long as you create an origin locator, rather than a SAS locator, the content should still be served through your reserved units.